# Beginner - What's wrong with my "produce word backwards" program?

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string word, wordbackw;

    getline(cin, word);
    int size = word.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++)
        word[size-1-i] = wordbackw[i];

    cout << wordbackw << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The only thing that appears in the cmd is my input.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Sorry, forgot to add cout to the code.

Comment: Other people have already explained the errors in your code. I'd just like to add that using iterators is nicer and avoids those pesky potential off-by-one errors: http://ideone.com/rufVTp

Answer (score 2):

You must first resize `wordbackw` to the same size as `word`:

- You could either initialize `wordbackw = word;` before the loop and print out the result in `word`.
- Or you could resize `wordbackw` before the loop and copy `word` letters to `wordbackw` letters (you do the oposite for now), and display the result in `wordbackw`

Comment: Could you demonstrate what you mean by your second point?
Also, I did 

wordbackw[i] = word[size-1-i];

instead of 

word[size-1-i] = wordbackw[i]; , which seemed to have fixed it. Just flipped the two.

Comment: @hiro yes, but flip the two is not sufficient you need a wordbackw.resize(word.size()) before starting the loop. If you don't do this wordbackw would remain an empty string and accessing an element with indexing would be undefined behavior

Answer (score 0):

You're missing any kind of code to display the reversed string. You only reversed it in memory.

Try adding something to display the text after you reverse it, such as

```
cout << wordbackw;
```

Oh, well and also your word swapping code looks backwards in a couple of ways. You load it into word but then try to set word to the reverse of wordbackw, which is empty. Also the indexing looks off - you're assigning locations in an empty string, and you're indexing forwards through the source string rather than backwards. So you'd want to do something more like:

```
for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
    wordbackw += word[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

The object `wordbackw` is empty. So you may not apply the subscript operator for the object. Also you should at least exchange the operands in this statement

```
word[size-1-i] = wordbackw[i];
```

provided that the operands will be written correctly.

You could write instead of this code snippet

```
int size = word.size();

for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++)
    word[size-1-i] = wordbackw[i];
```

the following

```
wordbackw.reserve( word.size() );

for ( auto i = word.size(); i != 0 ; i-- )
    wordbackw.push_back( word[i - 1] );
```

Or

```
wordbackw.reserve( word.size() );

for ( auto i = word.size(); i != 0 ; i-- )
    wordbackw += word[i - 1];
```

Or you could do the same without using the loop. For example

```
wordbackw.assign( word.rbegin(), word.rend() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. You are overriding the input that you read with non-existent characters when you do `word[size-1-i] = wordbackw[i];` try doing `wordbackw.push_back(word[size-1-i]);`
2. You are not printing anything to the standard output after reading. Do this
   `cout << wordbackw << endl;`